# Threading not successful

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, scheduler

I'm doing Tkinter. My functions run correctly (playing a bell sound once a minute), but it's not running on a thread. Whenever I click the Start button, the program window grays out and the top says "Not responding" (because my recursive calls to start() are locking it, I'm assuming.)

Why am I not threading correctly? Thanks.

```
def start():
    now = tt1.time()
    listOfTimes = []
    for t in timeSlotEFs:
        listOfTimes.append(t.get())
    now = datetime.now()
    timee = now.strftime('%H%M')
    print('here')
    for t in listOfTimes:
        if t==timee:
            winsound.PlaySound('newhourlychimebeg.wav',winsound.SND_FILENAME)
    s.enterabs(now+60,1,start) #I want to call recursively every 60 seconds
    s.run()
def start2():
    t = threading.Thread(target=start)
    t.run()            
startBtn = Button(ssFrame, text='Start', command=start2)
startBtn.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=paddX,pady=paddY)
```

Comment: Your question should remain strictly a question. If you want to post an answer with "in `start2()`, change `t.run()` to `t.start()`" you are encouraged to do so, though I guess the accepted answer already more or less covers that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels like you mixed between the definitions that **threading.Thread** imports from.
You should create run function and then **start** the thread.

This way i see the result and it works:

```py
from tkinter import *
import threading
root = Tk()

def run():
    print('hello Thread')

def start2():
    t = threading.Thread(target=run)
    t.start()
    print(t) # Output: <Thread(Thread-1, stopped 10580)>


startBtn = Button(root, text='Start', command=start2)
startBtn.grid(row=0,column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

In `start2()`, I changed `t.run()` to `t.start()`. That was it, and it now works. Thx Jim.